# how to query two column of same table with two condition with groupby

Tags: sql-server

```
Table :tbl_user
dateofregistration  ID     registrationstate
6-03-11              3          0
6-03-11              1          0
6-03-11              2          1
7-03-11              2          1
7-03-11              1          1
```

how can I display result like this for sql server 2008 express

```
date     TotalID(count)           Total State(0 only)
6-03-11      3                           2
7-03-11      2                           0
```

I have tried with this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), dateofregistration, 103) AS Date, 
(select COUNT(ID)) AS Subbase, 
(Select Count(ID)from tbl_User where (registrationstate='0')) AS Totalchurn
FROM  tbl_User 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), dateofregistration, 103);
```

but wrong result.Any help plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about;

```
select 
    cast(dateofregistration as date),
    count(distinct id),  --or * for all
    sum(
        case registrationstate when '0' then 1 else 0 end
    )
from tbl_user
    group by cast(dateofregistration as date)
    order by 1


2011-06-03  3   2
2011-07-03  2   0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), dateofregistration, 103) AS Date, 
COUNT(1) AS Subbase, 
SUM(CASE WHEN registrationstate='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Totalchurn
FROM  tbl_User 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), dateofregistration, 103)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: You are lacking a closing paren afer the `END` for the `CASE`

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there. You don't need a subselect for COUNT(ID) since that is handled by the GROUP BY. You group by date, and so the count will be the number of IDs within each date. I've made the count distinct, just in case you can have multiple registrations of the same ID on one day.

Your subquery was almost right - it needs to be correlated with the main query by selecting rows with the same registration date.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), dateofregistration, 103) AS Date, 
COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS TotalID, 
(Select Count(*) from tbl_User t2 where (registrationstate='0') AND t2.registrationdate=t1.registrationdate) AS Totalchurn
FROM  tbl_User t1
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), dateofregistration, 103);
```